# How can i make a multipart/form-data request with string

Tags: c#, request

I'm trying to make a request on this site: https://textitor.com/ to create pastes but I saw that the content-type was multipart/form-data.

I saw on Stackoverflow several explanations to make a multipart/form-data request with a file but I couldn't find how to do it with strings.

So I'm hoping that someone will be able to help me

You can see below Request Header & Parameter:

```
Host: api.textitor.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:74.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/74.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: fr,fr-FR;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------224061383921529899882446413168
Content-Length: 797
Origin: https://textitor.com
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://textitor.com/
TE: Trailers
```

```
-----------------------------224061383921529899882446413168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pastetitle"


-----------------------------224061383921529899882446413168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="pastetext"

testafefafafaaf
-----------------------------224061383921529899882446413168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="expirationtime"

never
-----------------------------224061383921529899882446413168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="viewlimit"

unlimited
-----------------------------224061383921529899882446413168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="syntaxlang"

none
-----------------------------224061383921529899882446413168
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="ispublic"

false
-----------------------------224061383921529899882446413168--
```

Comment: A file you use StreamReader/StreamWriter.  A String you use StringReader/StringWriter (or a MemoryStream).

Comment: Hmm i will try.